# Creating an additional row containing the average value

Tags: sql, sas

I am having the following dataset.

```
data pain;
    input SUBJID$ XOCAT$ XOTEST$ VISIT$ XOSTRESN XOSTRESU$ EPOCH $9.;
    datalines;
101-01 OD pressure Visit2 20 mmHg Screening
101-01 OD pressure Visit2 .  mmHg Screening
101-01 OD pressure Visit2 .  mmHg Screening
101-01 OD pressure Visit2 40 mmHg Screening
101-01 OD pressure Visit2 .  mmHg Screening
101-01 OD pressure Visit3 21 mmHg Treatment
101-01 OD pressure Visit4 22 mmHg Treatment
101-01 OD pressure Visit5 25 mmHg Treatment
;
run;
```

I would like to get the output with one additional row with the average of XOSTRESN value (i.e. 20+40/2=30);

The output will contain the following additional row:

```
101-01 OD pressure visit2 30 mmHg Screening.
```

I tried to use proc sql to create an average. But are there any alternate and better way to do the same?

Comment: post what you've tried so far. Please review the SO guidelines for posting a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you did?

```
Proc sql;
    select subjid, xocat, xotest, epoch, avg(xostresn)
    from pain
    group by subjid, xocat, xotest, epoch;
```

This does add the extra row.  You would use a `union all` for that, but it gives the idea.